# How to set Time and Date on Raspberry Pi with c?

Tags: c++, c, time, raspberry-pi

I am using the extension `SD0` from Busware for the Raspberry Pi. On it is the OS Raspbian. The Raspberry Pi doesn't have internet connection. SD0 contains the `RTC ds1338`.

How is it possible to set the Time and Date of the Raspberry Pi with the language C or C++?
I know more or less, how to connect over I2C.

Answer (score 2):

You can always call the commandline tool inside your C code:

```
settimeofday(timeval, NULL);
system("hwclock --systohc")
```

Or you can direct access your rtc device-driver trough ioctl interface. (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/rtc.h)

Example:

```
struct rtc_time rtc = {};
tnow.tm_year = 2015; /* fill up entire struct */
int fd = open("/dev/rtc0", O_RDWR)
ioctl(fd, RTC_SET_TIME, &tnow);
close(fd);
```

Comment: thanks for the code examples. My question was gone in direction, how to set the Time after build a I2C Connection, like the second example.

Answer (score 2):

If this is what you are asking: the `settimeofday(2)` system call sets the time on Unix.
You need to be root to do so. Loosely:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = seconds since 1 jan 1970;
tv.tv_usec = 0; /* microseconds */
if(settimeofday(&tv, NULL) == 0)// it was ok
```

See `mktime(3)` for how to convert a date into seconds in C.

Answer (score 2):

Along with  using [settimeofday()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/settimeofday) from the  library I though i'd add your going to want to make sure you've configured I2C on the pi and turn on the driver for the ds1338 clock on the pi as well, look here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=25399

i'm assuming you would do something like:

```
modprobe i2c-bcm2708
echo ds1338 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-0/new_device
modprobe rtc-ds1338
hwclock -s
```

Very cool entension board btw, didn't know this smart reader existed.